# In SOLARIS 10 ZFS, I want Hot spare pool and want to associate its 1st disk with rpool and 2nd disk with the xpool. What will be the complete method?

Tags: filesystems, solaris-10, zpool, solaris-11, pool

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrNsC.png)
**This is the Current two pools that I have, and now want to associate Hot Spare disks with it, so please help**

Comment: paste text always directly

Comment: what did u mean I didn't understand?

Comment: Do not post images, post text!

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to post photo for clarification but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why would you add *spares* to a RAID-1 mirror?  Just add the disks to the mirrors and make them three-disk mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use commands like:

```
zpool add rpool spare c2t3d0
zpool add xpool spare c2t4d0
```

This will add `c2t3d0` as spare to `rpool`. Similar about the other disk.

Comment: Well Thanks I know that, but I want a different pool for hot spare with two disks, (I think those disks will show up something like hsp001 and hsp002, that's what my senior told me) and then associate the first disk with rpool and 2nd disk with xpool

Comment: @Shehryarkh95, I do not think you can add disks in pool and then add them as spare in other pool